# Do we have request/response logs available in audit logs for Endpoints in GCP Vertex AI platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ai

We trained autoML models and deployed on Endpoints in GCP vertex AI platform. We are looking for request/response logs for all the requests made to the Endpoint. Are these logs available, if yes then how we can access them?

Relevant URL: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/audit-logging#enabling_audit_logging

Comment: Do you want the request/response content?

Comment: Yes, If possible. 
And in vertex AI platform, models monitoring is shown as disabled. We are not able to enable them. We are hoping to see more detailed logs once it is enabled.

Comment: Try to activate the audit logs but I doubt that the request/response content are logged. The best solution is to wrap the call in a proxy Cloud Function that log the traffic for you.

Comment: In this documentation page, it is described that you can enable **Request-response logging** but I don't see such option on the UI, only **Access logging**. https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/online-prediction-logging